# parsing xml file in ipad

Tags: ipad

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  <IPAD version="1.0"> 
<articleSnapshot>
<item>
<categoryName>Kerala</categoryName>
<oid>2915</oid>
<title>ÎÆcÈÏ¢: ÄßøáJW ÕçKAá¢</title>
<thumbImage>http://122.248.234.55/v3/repository/images/news/bar-liquor_thuthumb_2915.jpg</thumbImage>
<shortDescription>ÎÆcÈÏÕá¢ ¥Äßæa dÉ~cÞÉÈÕáÎÞÏß ÌtæMGí ©ÏVK ÕßÎVÖÈBZ ÏáÁß®Ëá¢...</shortDescription>
</item>
</articleSnapshot>
</IPAD>
```

I want to parse this xml file and display it in viewdidload.i have completed the coding.but cant display in image view and textview seperately.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I parse an XML file very similar to yours. This basically converts the XML into a plist file.

```
#pragma mark - Delegate Received

-(void)parsingComplete:(XMLDataSource*)theParser {
    NSArray *categoryArray = [theParser getCategories];
    [categoryArray writeToFile:PLIST atomically:YES];
}
- (void)receivedItems:(NSArray *)theItems {
    NSMutableArray *dataItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [dataItems addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:PLIST]];

    NSDictionary * dataItem = [dataItems objectAtIndex:categoryIndex];
    data_ =  [dataItem objectForKey:@"images"];
}

#pragma mark - Parsing Delegates

- (void)parse:(NSData *)data withDelegate:(id)sender onComplete:(SEL)callback 
{
    parentDelegate = sender;
    onCompleteCallback = callback;
    loading = YES;

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    parsed = NO;
    loading = NO;
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
    NSString *element = [elementName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    currentElement = element;
    if ([[currentElement lowercaseString] isEqual:@"image"]) {
        inImage = YES;
        itemsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [itemsDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];
    }

    if ([[currentElement lowercaseString] isEqual:@"category"]) {
        inCategory = YES;
        categoryDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [categoryDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
    NSString *element = [elementName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if ([[element lowercaseString] isEqual:@"image"]) {
        inImage = NO;
        [items addObject:[itemsDictionary copy]];
    }

    if ([[element lowercaseString] isEqual:@"category"]) {
        inCategory = NO;
        [categoryDictionary setObject:[items copy] forKey:@"images"];
        [items removeAllObjects];
        [categories addObject:[categoryDictionary copy]];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSString *stringValue = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString *element = [currentElement stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    /*  skip over blank elements.  */
    if (stringValue == nil || [stringValue isEqual:@""]) {
        return;
    }

    if (element != nil && [element length] > 0) {
        if (inImage) {
            if ([itemsDictionary objectForKey:element] != nil) {
                [itemsDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [itemsDictionary objectForKey:element], stringValue]
                                    forKey:element];
            } else {
                [itemsDictionary setObject:stringValue forKey:element];
            }
        } else if ((!inImage) && (inCategory)) {
            if ([categoryDictionary objectForKey:element] != nil) {
                [categoryDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [categoryDictionary objectForKey:element], stringValue]
                                       forKey:element];
            } else {
                [categoryDictionary setObject:stringValue forKey:element];
            }
        } else {
            if ([root objectForKey:element] != nil) {
                [root setObject:stringValue forKey:element];
            }
        }
    }
}
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSError * err;
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:PLIST]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:PLIST error:&err];
    }
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
{
    parsed = YES;
    loading = NO;

    if ([parentDelegate respondsToSelector:onCompleteCallback]) {
        [parentDelegate performSelector:onCompleteCallback withObject:self];
    }

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(receivedItems:)])
        [self receivedItems:items];
    else
        SHOW_ALERT(@"parserDidEndDocument:", @"receivedItems: not responding!", nil, @"Okay", nil)
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Setters / Getters

- (id)delegate {
    return self;
}
- (void)setDelegate:(id)new_delegate {
    _delegate = self;
}
- (BOOL)isSuccessful {
    return success;
}
- (BOOL)isLoading {
    return loading;
}
- (BOOL)isParsed {
    return parsed;
}
- (NSArray *)getCategories {
    return categories;
}
- (NSDictionary *)getRoot {
    return root;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: but where to put my strings catogery,thumbimage,title,oid,shortdiscription and mutable array article snapshot.

Comment: this doesn't require you define your keys from the XML, it will grab the keys / values for you.

Comment: sir i didnt understand it,can u please explane how can i done with my above xml file.